# Surveys which capture income of individuals and other details

Tags: data-request

Please provide list of surveys which capture income of individuals, income determinants like education, age, work experience, field of work etc and, details about his family particularly number of elder brothers. Geography of Interest is US, Europe, Japan and Australia. Time period of interest is post 1980.

Comment: http://asdfree.com

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps:

Quandl's [Tax Policy Center](https://www.quandl.com/data/TPC) database shows US median income by age range, during a certain time frame and has data on median income outside cities vs metropolitan areas. You can search for "income"" within the database to see the all the different datasets. Or, actually, you can try going to this link directly: https://www.quandl.com/data/TPC?keyword=age%20income

Also, Quandl's [Bureau of Economic Analysis](https://www.quandl.com/data/BEA) database has data on US income. Search for "income" within the database and you'll get datasets such as National Income by Type of Income etc.

[Disclosure: I work for Quandl]